# How can I access to assets/image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I do have the image called `18.png` in `assets/images/languages/`

then I do have the attribute called `language`
Assuming, current_user.language = `18`

How can I access and show the image in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply append the users language attribute to a relative language asset path inside your view.

```
<%= image_tag "languages/#{current_user.language}.png" %>
```

If this is something you're going to be using throughout your application you should move it into a helper method, e.g. :

```
def user_locale_tag
  image_tag "languages/#{current_user.language}.png"
end
```

In your authentication system you'll want to ensure that current_user exists before hand.

Comment: @Cycle Thanks so much:) could you please show that in regular scripting? not haml please.

Comment: Thanks. I tried second one with helper. however, it's not showing:( assets pipeline and pre-compile matter? I'm using 3.2.11. This is the output what I got `<img alt="En" src="/languages/EN">England`

Comment: Try the updated solution, I had an extra forward slash in both examples and it was missing the png extension (also changed method name to user_locale_tag from user_local_tag).